# matlab, how do i write a statement that will give me time on xaxis from y=0.3

Tags: matlab

```
x=[0:.01:10];
y=(x.^2).*(exp(-x));

plot(x,y), grid
y1=max(y);

xlabel('TIME');
ylabel('CONCENTRATION IN BLOOD');
title('CONCENTRATIN OF SUSTANCE IN BLOOD vs TIME');

fprintf('(a) The maximum concentraion is %f \n',y1)
```

That's my program, and I'm having trouble to write a statement that will give me the time at when `y=0.3` please assist
thank you

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please accept an answer if you found it solving your problem.

Answer (score 4):

One key issue here is that there are multiple points on your plot where `y = 0.3`. If you want to find all of them in a simple way, you can follow these steps:

- Subtract 0.3 from your vector `y`, so that the points you want to find become zero crossings.
- Find the indices in the above vector where there is a sign change.
- For the `y` values on either side of the zero crossings, compute the percentage of the difference between them at which the value 0.3 lies. This essentially performs a linear interpolation between the two points on either side of the zero crossing.
- Use the above percentage to find the corresponding value of `x` for the zero crossing.

And here's the code along with a plot to show the points found:

```
>> yDesired = 0.3;
>> index = find(diff(sign(y-yDesired)));
>> pctOfDiff = (yDesired-y(index))./(y(index+1)-y(index));
>> xDesired = x(index)+pctOfDiff.*(x(index+1)-x(index))

xDesired =

    0.8291    3.9528

>> plot(x,y);
>> hold on;
>> plot(xDesired,yDesired,'r*')
>> xlabel('x');
>> ylabel('y');
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A straightforward answer is:

```
find(min(abs(y- 0.3))== abs(y- 0.3))
```

giving

```
ans = 84
```

thus

```
x(84)
ans = 0.83000
```

Now, if you increase the resolution in `x`, you'll also be able to find a solution closer to the analytical one.

```
> x=[0.5:.000001:1]; y=(x.^2).*(exp(-x));
> x(find(min(abs(y- 0.3))== abs(y- 0.3)))
ans =  0.82907
```

**Edit**:
And of'course in order to find all zeros:

```
> x=[0:.01:10]; y=(x.^2).*(exp(-x));
2> find(abs(y- 0.3)< 1e-3)
ans =
    84   396
> x(find(abs(y- 0.3)< 1e-3))
ans =
   0.83000   3.95000
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the symbolic toolbox in MATLAB, you can do the following

```
syms x
x=solve('x^2*exp(-x)=y')

x=
  (-2)*lambertw(k, -((-1)^l*y^(1/2))/2)
```

Here [`lambertw`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/symbolic/lambertw.html) is the solution to `y=x*exp(x)`, which is available as a function in MATLAB. So you can now define a function as,

```
t=@(y,k,l)(-2)*lambertw(k, -((-1)^l*y^(1/2))/2)
```

`lambertw` is a multivalued function with several branches. The variable `k` lets you choose a branch of the solution. You need the principal branch, hence `k=0`. `l` (lower case L) is just to pick the appropriate square root of `y`. We need the positive square root, hence `l=0`. Therefore,  you can get the value of `t` or the time for any value of `y` by using the function.

So using your example, `t(0.3,0,0)` gives `0.8291`.

**EDIT**

I forgot that there are two branches of the solution that give you real outputs (gnovice's answer reminded me of that). So, for both solutions, use

```
t(0.3,[0,-1],0)
```

which gives `0.8921` and `3.9528`.

Comment: Good analytical explanation, indeed. Now if OP is able to increase her resolution (in x) then the 'lookup' solution will be as well closer to the analytical one. Actually this a quite nice example of various ways to tackle a specific problem in `matlab`. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to find the index (and therefore x-value) is:

```
[minDiff, index] = min(abs(y-0.3))

minDiff =

  3.9435e-004


index =

    84

 x(index)

ans =

    0.8300
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the solutions already posted, I am adding other ways to solve the problem:

```
f = @(x) (x.^2).*(exp(-x));             %# function handle
y0 = 0.3;

format long

%# find root of function near s0
x1 = fzero(@(x)f(x)-y0, 1)              %# find solution near x=1
x2 = fzero(@(x)f(x)-y0, 3)              %# find solution near x=3

%# find minimum of function in range [s1,s2]
x1 = fminbnd(@(x)abs(f(x)-y0), 0, 2)    %# find solution in the range x∈[0,2]
x2 = fminbnd(@(x)abs(f(x)-y0), 2, 4)    %# find solution in the range x∈[2,4]
```

Comment: also my solution in another similar question would apply here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838796/solving-exponential-equation-in-matlab/6524396#6524396