# How to change returned functions parameters automatically in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, scientific-computing

I am doing a MATLAB assignment and it includes the evaluation of a returned `lambertw()` function. However, since I am doing Monte Carlo here, I need to use a branch of the function which is not the default branch. For example, change the parameter from the returned default zero

```
lambertw(0, -7661844165657387/9007199254740992*exp(-1))
```

to minus one

```
lambertw(-1, -7661844165657387/9007199254740992*exp(-1)).
```

Is there a way to do this automatically?

p.s. this is a follow up to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838796/solving-exponential-equation-in-matlab)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the result shown above stored in a symbolic variable `s`, one option you have is to use [CHAR](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/char.html) to convert the symbolic variable to a character string, use [STRREP](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/strrep.html) to replace the first argument to [LAMBERTW](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/symbolic/lambertw.html), then use [SYM](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/symbolic/sym.html) to convert the character string back to a symbolic equation:

```
s = sym(strrep(char(s),'lambertw(0','lambertw(-1'));
```