# Issues plotting graph matlab

Tags: matlab, graph, plot, equation

I did not find anything so far to my previous [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20054132/integration-of-a-system-of-differential-equations-matlab), I have therefore tackled the problem from another angle, but I still have a little problem. Here is my code:

```
%%calculation of Hopff bifurcation points
k = 0;
s = 1;
uhopf = 0;

while  s < 7
    s = s + 0.02;
    k = (s-1)*exp(-s);
    uhopf = s*k;
    %fprintf('s:  %.4f, k: %.4f, uhopf: %.4f\n', s, k, uhopf);
end

f = figure;
h = plot(uhopf, k);
xlabel('uhopf');
ylabel('k');
```

I was just wondering why can't I have a graph? Should I use "arrays" instead?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting the values `k` and `uhopf` on every iteration, so your code is just plotting one point (the last one).  Store each computed value in an array.

```
s = 1:0.02:7;
k = (s-1).*exp(-s);
uhopf = s.*k;
h = plot(uhopf, k);
```

Comment: I knew it! Thank you for your help, step by step I am learning the logic of matlab.